# Multi language Lemmatization in Python

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, data-science, lemmatization

I have a dataset in multiple languages. 
can I apply lemmatization according to its language?
I have already separated data according to its language.
Tried using WordNet lemmatization, but it only supports English language

For stemming in multiple languages, I am using snowballStemmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [spacy](https://spacy.io/)
It supports 34+ languages and it has a lemmatizer.